# "Class doesn't exist" error on Marketplace Sumission but class is there

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I have been trying to submit extension to Magento Marketplace but getting this error:

> Enabled maintenance mode Starting compilation Compilation was started.
>   %message% 0/7 [>---------------------------] 0% 1 sec 38.0
>   MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------] 0% 1 sec 38.0
>   MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------] 0% 1
>   sec 38.0 MiB Proxies code generation... 1/7
>   [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB Repositories code
>   generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB
>   Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------] 28%
>   7 secs 134.0 MiB Service data attributes generation... 2/7
>   [========>-------------------] 28% 7 secs 134.0 MiB Service data
>   attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------] 42% 7 secs
>   134.0 MiB Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------] 42% 7 secs 134.0 MiB Application code
>   generator... 4/7 [================>-----------] 57% 14 secs 154.0 MiB
>   Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------] 57% 14
>   secs 154.0 MiB Interceptors generation... 5/7
>   [====================>-------] 71% 22 secs 170.0 MiB Area
>   configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------] 71% 22
>   secs 170.0 MiB Area configuration aggregation... 6/7
>   [========================>---] 85% 30 secs 242.0 MiB Interception
>   cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---] 85% 30 secs
>   242.0 MiB Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 35 secs 242.0 MiB Generated code
>   and dependency injection configuration successfully. Compilation
>   complete Starting deployment of static content Something went wrong
>   while deploying static content. See the error log for details. Command
>   returned non-zero exit code: `/usr/bin/php -f
>   /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US`
>   + error=true
>   + '[' true ']'
>   + /bin/bash get_log.sh system [2017-06-15 12:57:56] main.INFO: /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1
>   Compilation was started. %message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]
>   0% 1 sec 38.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------] 0% 1 sec
>   38.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------] 0% 1 sec 38.0 MiB Proxies code generation... 1/7
>   [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB Repositories code
>   generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB
>   Repositories code generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------] 28%
>   7 secs 134.0 MiB Service data attributes generation... 2/7
>   [========>-------------------] 28% 7 secs 134.0 MiB Service data
>   attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------] 42% 7 secs
>   134.0 MiB Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------] 42% 7 secs 134.0 MiB Application code
>   generator... 4/7 [================>-----------] 57% 14 secs 154.0 MiB
>   Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------] 57% 14
>   secs 154.0 MiB Interceptors generation... 5/7
>   [====================>-------] 71% 22 secs 170.0 MiB Area
>   configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------] 71% 22
>   secs 170.0 MiB Area configuration aggregation... 6/7
>   [========================>---] 85% 30 secs 242.0 MiB Interception
>   cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---] 85% 30 secs
>   242.0 MiB Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 35 secs 242.0 MiB Generated code
>   and dependency injection configuration successfully. [] [] [2017-06-15
>   12:58:00] main.ERROR: /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy en_US 2>&1 Requested languages: en_US
>   Requested areas: adminhtml, frontend Requested themes:
>   Magento/backend, Magento/blank, Magento/luma
>   === adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
>   === frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
>   === frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
>
> [InvalidArgumentException] [InvalidArgumentException] Plugin class
>   Namespace\Module\Plugin\Model\Store doesn't exist Plugin class
>   Namespace\Module\Plugin\Model\Store doesn't exist
>
> [InvalidArgumentException] Plugin class
>   Namespace\Module\Plugin\Model\Store doesn't exist
>
> ```
> setup:static-content:deploy [-d|--dry-run] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html]
> ```
>
> [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-t|--theme[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-theme[="..."]] [-l|--language[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-language[="..."]] [-a|--area[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-area[="..."]] [-j|--jobs[="..."]] [--symlink-locale]
>   [languages1] ... [languagesN]
>       setup:static-content:deploy [-d|--dry-run] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html]
>   [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-t|--theme[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-theme[="..."]] [-l|--language[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-language[="..."]] [-a|--area[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-area[="..."]] [-j|--jobs[="..."]] [--symlink-locale]
>   [languages1] ... [languagesN]
>
> ```
> setup:static-content:deploy [-d|--dry-run] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html]
> ```
>
> [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-t|--theme[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-theme[="..."]] [-l|--language[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-language[="..."]] [-a|--area[="..."]]
>   [--exclude-area[="..."]] [-j|--jobs[="..."]] [--symlink-locale]
>   [languages1] ... [languagesN]
>
> === Minify templates ===
>
> ### Successful: 872 files modified
>
> New version of deployed files: 1497531478 [] []
>
> ```
> [Pipeline] }
> [Pipeline] // stage
> [Pipeline] stage
> [Pipeline] { (indexer:reindex)
> [Pipeline] sh
> ```

This is working fine on my end (localhost and server). Please help to resolve.

Comment: Same issue I have when submitting, but the class exists. Have you solved? Any clue

Answer (score 1):

Is your namespace name is “Namespace” and module name is “Module”, If yes, then according to the specified error ,class Plugin doesnt exist , track the  location i.e. go to Namespace\Module\Plugin\Model\Store and search for Plugin class.
Also, Make sure your file name is saved without any space as sometimes this might create an issue.

Comment: Well, I have checked such errors but there is no error like this. BTW, thanks a lot for the reply.